# How to generate positive and negative random numbers in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, random-number

In my VHDL testbench, I have a configurable parameter DATA_WIDTH which is set to power of 2 such as 16-bits.

I want to generate random signed numbers (2's compliment) of bit width as DATA_WIDTH. For example if DATA_WIDTH is 16 bits, then I want to generate random numbers in range -32,768 to 32,768 (all range inclusive).

As of now I am doing following (snippet of VHDL code, not complete):

```
variable W : natural                := 16;
variable seed1, seed2 : positive    := 1;
variable x_real: real               := 0.0;
variable x_int : integer            := 0;

variable data_vec std_logic_vector(W-1 downto 0) := ( others =>'0' );

uniform( seed1, seed2, x_real );
x_int := integer(floor(x_real * real(2**W)));

data_vec := std_logic_vector( to_signed( x_int, data_vec'LENGTH ) )
```

However, when I run the testbench simulation, I get following warnings from Modelsim:

> Warning: NUMERIC_STD.TO_SIGNED: vector truncated

There is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053715/how-can-i-get-random-numbers-between-1024-and-1024-in-vhdl), however the answer in that post doesn't offer solution using standard VHDL libraries but using Open Source VHDL Verification Methodology.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have:

```
x_int := integer(floor(x_real * real(2**W)));
```

Your generated values for `x_int` are in the range of 0 to 2**W, so for W=16, you get values from 0 to 65535.

But then next up you convert to a signed vector:

```
data_vec := std_logic_vector( to_signed( x_int, data_vec'LENGTH ) );
```

The problem is that a signed value of W bits can only represent -2<sup>W-1</sup> to 2<sup>W-1</sup>-1.  So anytime the call to `uniform` generates a value greater than 2<sup>W-1</sup>-1, you exceed the range of your vector.

Since `uniform` returns a value in the range (0.0, 1.0), you need to scale your random value to be (-1.0, 1.0), then apply 2<sup>W-1</sup>.  Though this is equivalent to scaling your random value to (-0.5, 0.5) and then apply 2<sup>W</sup>.

EDIT:  Alternatively, you can use `to_unsigned`, for which 2<sup>W</sup> is fine (`unsigned` vectors have a range of 0 to 2<sup>W</sup>-1).  And since this is just going into an amorphous vector, will work fine.

```
data_vec := std_logic_vector( to_unsigned( x_int, data_vec'LENGTH ) );
```

Comment: "Your generated values for x_int are in the range of 0 to 2**W, so for W=16, you get values from 0 to 65536." Fencepost error. Max value is 65535.